# JSON Spawning mysql sleep processes

Tags: php, javascript, json, game-development

I am in the process of making a Javascript(Front end, PHP back end) game.  In this game it checks the server for updates every 2 seconds.  There is one 1 sql call being run and at the end I use $mysqli->close() to close the SQL connection.  The columns in the where are both indexed.

The problem I am having is after its running for a little while MYSQL starts spawning tons of sleep processes.  Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275741/high-frequency-ajax-and-mysql-sleep-overload/2275794#2275794

Comment: I don't know if that's the exact same, but I can't give someone a solid php process for the entire length of a game.  Comet does not seem like it would be intended to use with PHP.  From what I read I'd have to keep a process open for people the entire time for one game.  That's just wasteful, I can't solve the problem by making the server even slower.

The problem I am having is a mysql issue not a javascript issue, there is no guarantee that this wouldn't spawn sleeps as well.  Not to mention the enormous amount of php processing.

Comment: Polling every 2 seconds isn't all that much more efficient than just keeping a process running

Comment: @Iscariot - but you're polling every 2 seconds. Multiply that by the number of users playing your game... that isn't much more efficient either.

Comment: That doesn't make since to me.  Perhaps I am wrong and you know better then I, but if every 2 seconds I run a process that takes 12-20ms and I run that once every 2 seconds for 5 minutes that would be.

3000 ms (at 20ms)

OR

300,000ms for leaving it running.

Is that wrong of me to think that leaving it on would be detrimental?   I am not perfect, that's why I am asking for help, so if I am wrong please show me the error of my ways.

Comment: Look at it from the perspective of a number of requests hitting your server *at the same time*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd push updates to your users instead of polling for them. Check out the [AJAX Push Engine](http://www.ape-project.org/), that can help a lot. Also, turn on persistent MySQL connections, that could help.

Answer (score 0):

Do the processes stick around?  Mysql likes to keep a few threads open to recieve requests, i wouldn't worry about them unless it leaving a lot of them open and there taking up resources.

If your hitting the request every 2 seconds its cheaper to keep the pool waiting for a request than instantiating a connection every time.

Comment: It starts off as one or two and quickly becomes 20-40 and page loads go from 223ms to 10 seconds.  I can't ignore the problem.